# How to save programmatically new tag in joomla

Tags: joomla, tags

In joomla we have api to save article:

```
require_once (JPATH_BASE.'/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php'); 
$new_article = new ContentModelArticle();
$data = array(
    'title' => "new article",
    'introtext' => "This is new article",
    'fulltext' => "The End!",
);
$new_article->save($data);
```

now i want add tags in my article. `#new` `#article` `#End`
How can i do it?

Comment: Are you saying you want those three terms as the tags and they may or may not exist?

Answer (score 2):

Insert the tags in array format.

```
$new_article->newTags = ['ID_tag_one', 'ID_tag_two', 'etc']; //array of tag IDs
```

Comment: Just by the fact that you say "array of tag IDs" and then are showing an array of strings, you are making  this answer  confusing.

Comment: O.K. edit my answer... ['ID_tag_one', 'ID_tag_two', 'etc']

Comment: So what I mean is you should say you want an array of strings. Saying it is an array of IDs implies an array of integers.